# How do i remove a merged excel cell with pandas for further processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

[image: sample excel sheet]

I want to remove the row that contains 'Some Random Text', how do I do that?
The actual names of the columns are in the row under that row...
[image: this is the output of print(df)]

[image: I want it to look like this.]

I want it to look like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reading the excel sheet add the skiprows keyword argument: `skiprows=[0]`

Answer (score 1):

setting the header parameter of read_excel to 1 solved it~

```
pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = df.loc[0]
df.drop(index = 0, inplace = True)
```

Comment: that didnt work..., i need to remove the column names so that row2 can be the column names...

Comment: Sorry, if you do df.columns = df.loc[0] (df.loc[0] being the row containing your new columns), then drop any unwanted rows df.drop(index = ?, inplace = True)